# Chrome Puppeteer - See what puppeteer is sending to chrome websocket/console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

Is there a way to grab or see exactly what chrome puppeteer is sending to/through the websocket?

For example, say I have this chrome Puppeteer command:

```
await page.mouse.click(112,106)
```

From reading the [documentation here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.3.0&show=api-mouseclickx-y-options), it says puppeteer's mouse.click is a shortcut for mouse.move, mouse.down, and mouse.up.

I'm wanting to know exactly what commands and functions, and how it's sending it to chrome to react the way it does so I can try and implement it in some other scripts of mine.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can see this?

Comment: Try to select the node (inspector tab) in Chrome Dev Tools, then run `monitorEvents($0)` in console tab

Comment: Maybe https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#monitor can help.

Comment: It seems it cannot or I am doing this wrong: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5977

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Thank you for opening up a thread on the github! Hopefully we'll get a good answer!